# Map json data in object from interface with typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I´m trying to put data from an Excel-Sheet into a json object. For this I created a structure Info object for reading the excel, and a Thing interface for the object that should receive the data. As you can see they have 1:1 attribute names Thing:excelStructure.structure

```
export const excelStructure: { [key: string]: any } = {
    "headerRow": 1,
    "firstdatarow": 3,
    "structure": {
        "sortierung": "A",
        "stockwerk": "B",
        "raum": "C",
        "objekt": "D",
        "typ": "E",
        "aktor": "F",
        "aktorausgang": "G",
        "ga_schalten": "H",
        "ga_dimmer": "I",
        "ga_helligkeit": "J",
        "ga_schaltzustand": "K",
        "ga_wert": "L",
        "groups": "M",
        "allow_export": "N"
    }
}


export interface Thing{
    sortierung: string
    stockwerk: string
    raum: string
    objekt: string
    typ: string
    aktor: string
    aktorausgang: string
    ga_schalten: string
    ga_dimmer: string
    ga_helligkeit: string
    ga_schaltzustand: string
    ga_wert: string
    groups: string
    allow_export: string

}
```

Now I want to create a loop in which I read the data from excel and fill the Thing object.

```
var dataObject:Thing = {
                    ...excelStructure.structure
                } //to initialize the Thing object with something. Don´t know if I need it :-(
                
                for (const key in excelStructure.structure) {
                    dataObject[excelStructure.structure[key]] = sh.getRow(idx).getCell(excelStructure.structure[key]).value
```

The IDE complains this:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Thing'.ts(7053)
```

is there a smooth way to do this without having to map it attribute to attribute myself ?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That

```
dataObject[objKey] = sh.getRow(idx).getCell(key).value as string
```

did the trick!.
Thanks @yong Shun!

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt with `keyof typeof dataObject`.

```js
for (const key in excelStructure.structure) {
   let objKey = key as keyof typeof dataObject;
   dataObject[objKey] = /* value */;
}
```

[Sample Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgD2HANgZSgJwK7CtzOALhgG8YBtAazgE8TpMBLMAcwF0SBDMWmAXxgBeMgCgYEgEQALOFwAmcTACUQAd0kkAjABpxUgGZNM0eVyhdM6zTADMeiTEmNc+QjdL7HTiCExQmJWw2G0kAQUkHbx8oEGAqNSUqUIAhSK9HSUwubABbUIBhdOinEAAjACs4KihQgBFi6MkoWgAHUIBRRu9JLhq-UIAxbsy+2OzsCFYeVlCAcRGpaYB9CGBpLhQoODBQgAlFpxX5JlzcpVCASUPJFdkUFCZWGiZakkkAKRuVtY2tgC9JhYwPJQgBpb5cZaJfyhAAy3ys2FaEFCAFkbpsUOplohWn43k4AHKSLz8UTk0QsbaYAxcZAwAAq0hYrDEjl8-kCODYDCwrK80DiCSSfOYbC8E1yYoFjnKVRqMoljharSVrC8Yz86s1-QmUxmOscP3Wm22YCNEmOp3OmEtMDuqEezzgr3tJr+UEB0B48ndUJhUHdSJR9qxOLxBJ1lIAbpYYGYLAB5SpwPAkZms4TsiQAOnziGQ6CwrgIcFzLjwZYpMAA9LXYjAWK8mJsmP84DAoLImSy2DB5WnYGpXtIYL5zt3WbmYHVwAAW2BUMDqJsGGCXGBgOBweRN2BEAC0AApRKIDH4YMfQJAl3Qm2B4EhUBgcFXCBWS++4ABKHMwFA4FgeUwXvEQaD4LgIBgCCQHXVU4DghNzC4FMqjwABuLxE1Q1M8AoEC6HYbNCxfL83HLSsKOoIisMpG9fEA3NsVYY8cLQocfwwoA)

*Note: `excelStructure.structure[key]` returns the value but not `key`.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. First I was confused, that it´s that easy, but then I tried to blow it up again with the real thing (value from excelCell and got this:

Type 'CellValue' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

The code that got marked is the last line of this block:

var cellValue = sh.getRow(idx).getCell(excelStructure.structure[objKey]).value

                        console.log(cellValue)
                        dataObject[objKey] = cellValue

Comment: Hi, are your cell name is based on key of `excelStructure.structure` such as "sortierung" and etc.? If yes, you try `var cellValue = sh.getRow(idx).getCell(key).value`. I not sure what is `CellValue`, maybe you can mention the library used for it.

Comment: Hi, it´s exceljs

Comment: [`CellValue`](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/2ab468b8bae2c8d5844f922d61ac7d960fee26be/index.d.ts#L382) can be `string`, `number` and etc (type). For your scenario (all fields are string), you can work with `dataObject[objKey] = sh.getRow(idx).getCell(key).value as string`.